# Check if a specific row exists regarding its value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check if a string exists in a row in a specific table, i have had no luck in doing this but i was able to gain an understanding on how `$query->num_rows();` works and i thought i would have to do something like.

The code i tried below i thought will check if the d009 value exists in the dept_no row and if their are no rows with the value d009 then it should produce an error message.

When i run the code it does not echo any message

```
$this->db->where('dept_no', 'd009');

$query = $this->db->get('dept_manager');
if($query->num_rows()==0)
{
    echo "true";            
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

dept_manager table

```
d009 a
d008 b
d007 c
```

Comment: what you get if you use `echo $this->db->count_all_results();` just after `$this->db->get`

Comment: A bit of a puzzle... Is it ```echo "false";```, not ```echo false;``` (this one would be invisible)? Maybe it is inside some block that quietly catches all errors and execution never reaches those echoes for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `if.. else` should be opposite of what you have specified

```
if($query->num_rows()==0)
{
    echo "false";            
}
else
{
    echo "true";
}
```

I mean if num_rows() returns zero rows means value not present in the row....